# Full Text Search with ft_min_word_len less than 3 chars

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I'm using `MySQL 5.6 with InnoDB on Windows 10` and I want to change the Full Text Search minimum length because I want to perform searches even when the search query is less than 3 chars.

How to find and edit `my.ini` because I can not find it in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6`

Is there a better way doing Full Text Search with a word less than three chars?